# unable to start websphere application server v8.5

Tags: websphere-8, ibm-rad, ibm-was

I am not able to start *WAS v8.5* on *RAD*. When I start it, it initially starts but during publishing it stops and gives error

> "Publish is not performed since the server is not started. Start the
>   server before performing the publish operation."

I tried disabling the auto publish still it publishes and throws the error!

Comment: Any errors in the SystemOut.log? Also try to start the server from command line and see if it starts successfully.

Comment: Pls try creating a new profile. Looks like the first time you attempted to start the server, the application got published. And now it is in limbo. Always remove the application first, then publish, clean before stopping the server.

Comment: @Gas I were able to start the server from command line

Comment: The problem is solved by changing the Windows->Preferences->General-> network Connections -> Active providers from "Manual" to "Native"